# How to make Bootstrap 3 navbar affix move smoothly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

If you run the code snippet, it appears that the affix only moves down smoothly and does not move up smoothly, how do I achieve that? I wonder if there is something wrong with the position element, but seems I could not make it work well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet"      href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">        </script>
 <script     src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>

 <style>
   .affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
         }
    .affix-top {
       position: static;
       top: -35px;
        }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="190">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Basic Topnav</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="height:1000px">
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your code does nothing on my end? Do you want a fixed nav bar? I see you are trying to animate something but you question literally makes no sense.

Comment: the navbar (using affix) moves down smoothly (affected by ease-in-out transition) but when I scroll up, it does not goes up smoothly (this is my question)

Comment: Ok sorry havent used bootstrap in a while, thought you just wanted a fixed nav bar. So your current example is kind of wonky because of you page layout. There is no point figuring out what is doing it until you have your general page layout setup.

Comment: i think the code snippets should represents the idea already

Comment: In my opinion it doesn't. You cant scroll down far enough so its impossible to know what behavior you are trying to accomplish. If you look at these http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp demos then you will see what affix is meant to be used for. Your nav bar is at the top of the page. If you just want it to follow the page as you scroll down just used a fixed nav bar. It would be a terrible UX to have a semi fixed nav bar that lags behind the page scroll.

Comment: The idea behind is that I want to make the navbar appear only after certain height of the screen smoothly (done) and move back smoothly(not achieved). I can't think of other option apart from using affix, any idea?

Comment: Yea this is pretty easy to manually do with scrollTop. If you are using jquery (which you must be as you are using bootstrap) you can call .scroll() on the window object. Then in the callback function keep checking window.scrolltop() => 190px (or whatever point on the page that you want the nav bar to animate down at) Then just $('#navBar').addClass('my-animate-down-class')  to trigger the nav bar to animate down.

Comment: I have no idea how to integrate it with navbar though